# Why is there low-level and high-level assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, low-level

I want to learn assembly, but the kind of tutorials i com across seem to adhere to one of two sides: either [relatively] high level or everything built from scratch. Personally, i want to learn from the ground up how it works, but the tutorials i leafed through seem to go directly into a 64-bit version where you can just write anything. For example:

```
section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10    ; 'Hello world!' plus a linefeed character
    helloLen:  equ $-hello             ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
    mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
    mov ecx,hello        ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
    mov edx,helloLen     ; helloLen is a constant, so we don't need to say
  
  
    
    int 0x80             ; Call the kernel
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return "code" of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
    
num_to_string:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  
  
  
  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
```

Here is a basic hello world program that appears if i go on an asm compiler. It's using the `e_x` registers already, without anything to be written beforehand.

Meanwhile, in a (possibly pretty dated) tutorial of a beginner trying learn to write a bootloader and sharing it [(youtube playlist)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxN4E629pPnKKqYsNVXpmCza8l0Jb6l8-), he had to go through going from 16bit mode to protected 32bit mode and then to long mode (64bit).

I know the syntax varies based on architecture, but between the "bare-metal" one and the "high level" one, there seem to be clear differences in not exactly syntax, but how you code.

Comment: I think the crass difference you observed is due to writing application software for an existing OS (in which case you have a system service call for eg writing a string to the user display, and the executable format uses different sections in a standardised way) versus developing an "OS" of sorts based on just a boot loader (like the old timey ROM-BIOS passing control to your boot sector). You can however connect the two, and many concepts apply to both uses of assembly language. (Personally, I find I learn best from existing useful software rather than toy examples.)

Comment: The example code is 32 bit, not 64 bit.

Comment: Related: [How is FASM a low level assembler and NASM a high level assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66133054) - like I was talking about in comments under Alejandro's answer.  People do use those terms when talking about different assemblers, not different code for different environments using the same assembler syntax.  They don't have a specific technical meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "low level assembly" and "high level assembly". It's always the same thing put in different contexts.

For instance, the code you wrote makes heavy use of the OS (in this case `int 80h` is a call to the Linux kernel) and you don't do pretty much by yourself, because you just put a few strings in memory, call the OS and that's it, you have a hello world in a console.

In the case you mention of writting a bootloader, you're in a masively different environment. The computer has pretty much *nothing* in memory and you must work your way out of that into loading a fully working OS, by passing though mode changes and the like.

Both things differ only in the environment they exists in. When you run on top of an OS, you are just an application that calls the OS, while the OS talks to the hardware, manage memory, writes to disk, handles CPU resources and the like. When you write a bootloader (or worse, an operating system), you must do all that by yourself.

Comment: I see, that actually makes a lot of sense, thank you. Also, the "high level" and "low level" were just a way to differentiate between the two because i didn't know what the difference actually was; as for the title, it had to be short and concise, so i just put something that you could argue was a tad bit clickbaity to more easily get the point across.

Comment: Additionally, do you have any suggestions about how i should go about with learning it? Should i start with letting the os do the heavy lifting or should i go to the very base of it from the start? If you have any references it would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: There actually is a language called "High Level Assembly", HLA. (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hla/info). It uses more C-like syntax, and most lines still assembles to one x86 instruction.  But I think it might support one line expanding to passing multiple args to a function call or something, like MASM's `invoke` macro.  MASM also describes itself as "high level", having macros / directives like `.if` and `.while`, which I think were mostly useful for people stuck working on projects in asm when they'd rather not be writing asm.  These days you'd just use C for such code.

Comment: But yes, this is the correct answer to the question asked; "high level assembly" actually does exist as a term (mostly marketing, not strict technical meaning), but it's not used to distinguish between code for different environments like @Gajej is asking about.  (16-bit legacy BIOS MBR bootloaders vs. 64-bit UEFI applications vs. 32 or 64-bit Linux programs.  The code in the question being a 32-bit Linux program that will be started by the OS in 32-bit protected mode, or under a 64-bit OS in compat mode.  Or *could* be assembled into a 64-bit program that happens to work with 32-bit syscalls)

Comment: @PeterCordes - my understanding is the directives like `.if` and `.while` were dropped in Masm 64 bit (ML64.EXE). IBM also had multiple assemblers, BAL (basic assembly language), ALC,  assembler E, assembler F, assembler H, HLASM (high level assembly language), ... .

Comment: @rcgldr: Yup, apparently so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-while?view=msvc-170 documents `.while` as "32-bit MASM only", unlike assemble-time directives like `rept 10` to repeat a block of code. `invoke` is also gone in ML64, since the Windows x64 calling convention works best when your reserve shadow space at the top of the function, not on each call.  So that's good.  Code where optimization matters so little that stuff like `.while` is worth considering generally shouldn't be written in asm in the first place, and these days generally isn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes - the main point of directives `.if` , `.while`,  ... , was to reduce the number of labels .